# Is it possible to retrieve system, software and license information from a fleet of Windows computers?

Tags: audit

I would like to know the hardware and software information for a fleet of Windows PCs. That includes licenses that software is registered with. I would like the information to be in a simple text file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into [DameWare Development's NT Utilities](http://www.dameware.com/products/dntu/). The license scheme is very nice (you pay for one person to use it, no matter how many PCs you query with it). It also comes with their Mini Remote Control which is a nice remote control utility. You can use a 30 day trial that is fully featured to see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: +1 for Dameware. I used it years ago primarily to remote control W2K workstations but still find the utilities pretty handy. Also, the pricing model and the abiliuty to push the agent to remote hosts can't be beat.

Answer (score 2):

We have had good results with openaudit.

http://www.open-audit.org/

Comment: I am looking for more portable application which I can run as a logon script (maybe console application) in the workstations, without the need to install anything anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you check out Spiceworks:

http://www.spiceworks.com/

Free, works with AD and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Which way you want to go with this will depend heavily on how much time you want to invest vs how much you want to spend.  If you want to DIY and spend nothing, you can use your favorite method to talk to WMI, which has all the information you're after.  Tools such as Scriptomatic can make these scripts easier to write.

You can whip up a script to run at login, or - with the proper permissions - you can pull the information remotely (via RPC, I believe).

At the other end of the spectrum, you have inventorying & monitoring products like Nagios - you'll get dozens of results searching that name on SF.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just script, you can try use this one http://rapidshare.com/files/334675734/collect.vbs.html. It collects information about hardware and software using wmi and registry and saves to %temp%/desc.info.cfg

Answer (score 0):

opensource FusionInventory.org does software audits, product key enumeration, software installation, and many other things brought into a centralized mysql database.  Works over SSL for remote home users.  Once the script is run once, the service is installed and automatically updates.  10 years old.  mature.

Answer (score 0):

MvPCinfo http://www.mvpcinfo.com/PCinfo/intro.htm

It's amazing what it does. I have it started on every workstation and it performs an automatic inventory of installed programs, license keys, event viewer logs, and and and....

It collects all this info in a csv file which you can also load into their database program mvPCbase which allows you to sort, separate, and even make graphs with that information.

I was looking for a freeware solution for a long time but none came close to what this program  can do for $29USD.